# Remove White Background from SVG Stars

Tags: css, svg

I have this code to show stars from a decimal.

```css
.rating {
  width: 120px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}

.rating progress.rating-bg {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearence: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  color: orange;
}

.rating progress.rating-bg::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: orange;
}

.rating progress.rating-bg::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: orange;
}

.rating svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none;">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="fivestars">
      <path d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z M0 0 h24 v24 h-24 v-24" fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
      <path d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z M0 0 h24 v24 h-24 v-24" fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(24)"/>
      <path d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z M0 0 h24 v24 h-24 v-24" fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(48)"/>
      <path d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z M0 0 h24 v24 h-24 v-24" fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(72)"/>
      <path d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z M0 0 h24 v24 h-24 v-24" fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd"  transform="translate(96)"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="rating">
  <progress class="rating-bg" value="4.9" max="5"></progress>
  <svg><use xlink:href="#fivestars"/></svg>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ppolp/pen/mdQyezW

It works but I'm trying to figure out how to remove the white rectange bg from the stars. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: The star outline isn't the background, it's the shape you've drawn. I.e. you've drawn the inverse of what you think you have. So to set the colour of the star's "background" you'd set the fill in the SVG. You might want to redraw your stars as stars rather than the outline/background of stars instead.

Comment: You can use fill="#cccccc" instead of fill="white". As an observation: instead of using 5 times the same path you can reruse the path with <use>. In this case the <use> element would take an x attribute that can be use instead of the transform

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can wrap it all in a native JavaScript (JSWC) Web Component:

```html
<star-rating stars=5 rating="3.5"
             bgcolor="green" nocolor="grey" color="gold"></star-rating>
```

It is way easier if you create all SVG client-side, using a Custom Element (supported in all modern Browsers):

- copied **only the d-path** from a star icon
- Edited the d-path in https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ to a **100x100**
  viewBox/grid
- made it an **inverse** star by prepending `M0 0h100v100h-100v-100` to the path
- Created a new SVG file in a `0 0 N 100` viewBox to fit all stars.. see below
- Added a **background rectangle** setting **gold** color rating
- Used  inverse stars, each at an x-offset
- added **rectangles** ***covering*** all half-stars
- set inline events `onclick` and `onmouseover` on every "half-star"

```html
<star-rating stars=5 rating="3.5"
             bgcolor="green" nocolor="grey" color="gold"></star-rating>
<star-rating stars=7 rating="50%"
             bgcolor="rebeccapurple" nocolor="beige" color="goldenrod"></star-rating>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => console.log(evt.target.getAttribute("n")))

  customElements.define("star-rating", class extends HTMLElement {
    set rating( rate ) {
      if (!String(rate).includes("%")) rate = Number(rate) / this.stars * 100 + "%";
      this.querySelector("#rating").setAttribute("width", rate);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let { bgcolor, stars, nocolor, color, rating } = this.attributes;
      this.stars = ~~stars.value || 5;
      this.innerHTML = 
        `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${this.stars*100} 100" style="cursor:pointer;width:300px">`
      + `<rect width="100%" height="100" fill="${nocolor.value}"/>`
      + `<rect id="rating"  height="100" fill="${color.value}"  />`
        + Array(  this.stars     ).fill()
               .map((i, n) => `<path fill="${bgcolor.value}" d="M${ n*100 } 0h102v100h-102v-100m91 42a6 6 90 00-4-10l-22-1a1 1 90 01-1 0l-8-21a6 6 90 00-11 0l-8 21a1 1 90 01-1 1l-22 1a6 6 90 00-4 10l18 14a1 1 90 010 1l-6 22a6 6 90 008 6l19-13a1 1 90 011 0l19 13a6 6 90 006 0a6 6 90 002-6l-6-22a1 1 90 010-1z"/>`)
               .join("")
        + Array(  this.stars * 2 ).fill()
               .map((i, n) => `<rect x="${ n*50 }" n="${n}" opacity="0" width="50" height="100"`
                  + ` onclick="dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))" `
                  + ` onmouseover="this.closest('star-rating').rating = ${(n+1)/2}"/>`)
              .join("") 
      + "</svg>";

      this.rating = rating.value;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good idea to use the [`<progress>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) element. Instead of laying the progress bar and the SVG on top of each other you can use an SVG as a [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) on the progress bar. Here I defined a star mask that will be a mask for just one star and masked off five rectangles in another mask. This mask can then be applied to the progress bar.

I took the freedom to construct the star instead of using a path. When using masks like in this example it doesn't matter.

```js
document.forms.form01.range.addEventListener('change', e => {
  document.getElementById('rating').setAttribute('value', e.target.value);
});
```

```css
.rating progress.rating-bg {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearence: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 120px;
  color: orange;
  background-color: #ddd;
  mask: url(#m1);
}

.rating progress.rating-bg::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: orange;
}

.rating progress.rating-bg::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: block;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="star">
      <rect width="24" height="24" fill="white"/>
      <g transform="translate(12 12)">
        <rect id="r1" width="48" height="24" fill="black" transform="translate(0 7) rotate(24) skewX(-42)"/>
        <use href="#r1" transform="rotate(72)"/>
        <use href="#r1" transform="rotate(144)"/>
        <use href="#r1" transform="rotate(216)"/>
        <use href="#r1" transform="rotate(288)"/>
      </g>
    </mask>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect id="r2" width="24" height="24" fill="white" mask="url(#star)"/>
      <use href="#r2" transform="translate(24 0)"/>
      <use href="#r2" transform="translate(48 0)"/>
      <use href="#r2" transform="translate(72 0)"/>
      <use href="#r2" transform="translate(96 0)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="rating">
  <progress id="rating" class="rating-bg" value="2" max="5"></progress>
</div>
<form name="form01">
  <input type="range" name="range" step=".25" min="0" max="5" value="2">
</form>
```